# jquery get index of parent

Tags: jquery, indexing, parent

I'm facing an issue with Jquery and can't find the solution.

Here is my code structure :

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Click here</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Click here</div>
    <div class="child"> Click here</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Click here</div>
</div>
```

I'd like to retrieve the index of the parent div when I click on any child div. Like if I click on child element of second parent div, I'd like to get a 2. I can't find the right Jquery line to do this.

Anyone ever did this ?

Thanks

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/index/ ?  It's zero-based, so your second would need +1

Comment: Sadly jQuery(this).parent().index() always retrive me the same value, if I click on child of first parent or child of the second one.

Comment: And yeah I know for the +1 thx :)

Comment: Can you add your existing jquery?  The click event - are you using `() =>`?

Answer (score 1):

> [index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)
>
> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

```js
$(".child").click(function() {
  console.log($(this).closest(".parent").index() + 1);
});
```

```css
.parent {
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Click here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Click here</div>
    <div class="child"> Click here</div>
  </div>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"> Click here</div>
  </div>
</div>
```